# Change properties for iAd view created using canDisplayBannerAds

Tags: ios8, iad, adbannerview, candisplaybannerads

On iOS 8 the iAd banner automatically created by using `canDisplayBannerAd` is displayed with a white background: that does not suit the app design at all. So I need to change it.

How to do it ?
Changing the background color property is easy but how to access the iAd banner view?

On iOS7 it was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way by creating a `category` for `ADBannerView` and modifying background color property in it.

The modification is made in `willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow`.

```c
-(void) willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow {

    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```